# User-space memory editing programs

Tags: linux, memory, operating-system

How do programs that edit memory of other processes work, such as *Cheat Engine* and *iHaxGamez*? My understanding is that a process reading from (let alone writing to) another process' memory is immediate grounds for a segmentation fault.

Comment: You mention 'Cheat Engine' - does that mean you're only interested in Windows?

Comment: Pedantic, but I'd like to point out that "segmentation fault" doesn't actually mean "any memory error".

Comment: I'm mostly interested in Linux, actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gaining access to another processes memory under linux is fairly straightforward (assuming you have sufficient user privileges).

For example the file `/dev/mem` will provide access to the entire memory space of cpu. Details of the mappings for an individual process can be found in `/proc/<pid>/maps`.

Another example has been given [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/reading-proc-pid-mem-462646/).

Comment: /dev/mem isn't going to be very useful, even when examining /proc/pid/maps or /proc/pid/pagemap to find out where to access. What you probably want is /proc/pid/mem instead, which is the process's virtual memory rather than the physical memory.

Answer (score 2):

The operation system's hardware abstraction layer usually offers functions to manipulate the memory of other processes. In Windows, the corresponding functions are [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It has no reason to segfault; OS (kernel, ...) API is used to write.
Segfault occurs (get signalled) from OS when a process attempts to access it's own memory in a bad way (char[] overflow).

About the games: well, if a value is stored at an address, and gets read sometimes, then it could be modified before next reading occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WinAPI `WriteProcessMemory` to write to memory space of other process.

Also read some PE/COFF documentation and use `VirtualQueryEx` and `ReadProcessMemory` to know what and where to write.