# Programmatically fill field in activity of another application?

Tags: java, android

How i can programmatically fill fields in activity of another application? It is possible? What is right way?
Add: My app is root-granted. I know what is package is now in foregraund. I have name of open activity and name of field in activity. Also I have my value whitch i need to push in this field.

Comment: Can you please explain your question in detail?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly is your scenario ???

Comment: Can't be done unless you manage to modify the other apps memory directly. Like in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4082810/995891

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way of inter application communication is basically through Intents in the Android world. That assumes the receiver to specify the format it expects data to arrive.

Fields in an activity are private to that application, and should not be available for other Apps. This, if it would be possible, would be a huge security hole in the platform.

You can create custom keyboards, or other input methods (IMEs), which is specified [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html).

Comment: Vajk Hermecz, you help for solution my problem. I create my custom keyboard (IME). Can i get from my IME names of alien activity and editable view ?

Answer (score 0):

InterProcess Communication (`IPC`) can be done only through the `AIDL` interface.

you shoul start from [there](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)